# #neo4j ERROR [o.n.k.h.c.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher]: Error while trying to switch to slave

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Issues with neo4j-ent 2.0 on ubuntu 13.04 joining cluster as a slave.  Server instance is stuck trying to become a slave.

> ERROR [o.n.k.h.c.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher]: Error while trying to switch to slave
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MismatchingStoreIdException:

**Cluster setup:**

1 embedded neo4j 2.0 frontend java service

1 neo4j-arbiter 2.0

1 neo4j-service 2.0

**Actions taken that led to this cluster state:**

1. started with neo4j embedded service
2. launched arbiter instance

> 2014-01-23 02:03:59.903+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$1]: LearnerState: start-[join]->learner conversation-id:5/3#
>   2014-01-23 02:03:59.904+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.AcceptorState$1]: AcceptorState: start-[join]->acceptor conversation-id:5/3#
>   2014-01-23 02:03:59.929+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]: Learned and closed instance 2 from conversation 5/3# and the content was Change cluster config, join:5
>   2014-01-23 02:03:59.930+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]: LearnerState: learner-[learn]->learner from:cluster://192.168.0.3:5001 instance:2 conversation-id:5/3#
>   2014-01-23 02:03:59.932+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.AtomicBroadcastState$2]: AtomicBroadcastState: joining-[broadcastResponse]->joining conversation-id:5/3#
>   2014-01-23 02:03:59.934+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.c.ClusterState$3]: ClusterState: joining-[configurationChanged]->entered conversation-id:5/3#
>   2014-01-23 02:03:59.934+0000 INFO  [o.n.c.c.ClusterJoin]: Joined cluster:Name:neo4j.ha Nodes:{3=cluster://192.168.0.3:5001, 5=cluster://192.168.0.5:5001} Roles:{coordinator=3}

1. started the backend neo4j-ent 2.0 instance from our 3rd machine
   **Arbiter Logs**

> ClusterState: entered-[configurationRequest]->entered
>   from:cluster://192.168.0.2:5001 conversation-id:1/12# 2014-01-23
>   02:08:44.962+0000 INFO  [o.n.c.c.NetworkSender]:
>   cluster://192.168.0.5:5001 opened a new channel to /192.168.0.2:5001
>   2014-01-23 02:08:44.981+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.AcceptorState$2]:
>   AcceptorState: acceptor-[prepare]->acceptor
>   from:cluster://192.168.0.3:5001 instance:3 conversation-id:1/12#
>   2014-01-23 02:08:44.990+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.AcceptorState$2]:
>   AcceptorState: acceptor-[accept]->acceptor
>   from:cluster://192.168.0.3:5001 instance:3 conversation-id:1/12#
>   2014-01-23 02:08:44.995+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]:
>   Learned and closed instance 3 from conversation 1/12# and the content
>   was Change cluster config, join:1 2014-01-23 02:08:44.996+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]: LearnerState: learner-[learn]->learner
>   from:cluster://192.168.0.3:5001 instance:3 conversation-id:1/12#
>   2014-01-23 02:08:44.996+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.AtomicBroadcastState$3]: AtomicBroadcastState:
>   broadcasting-[broadcastResponse]->broadcasting conversation-id:1/12#
>   2014-01-23 02:08:44.997+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.c.ClusterState$4]:
>   ClusterState: entered-[configurationChanged]->entered
>   conversation-id:1/12# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.030+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.e.ElectionState$2]: ElectionState:
>   election-[vote:coordinator]->election from:cluster://192.168.0.2:5001
>   conversation-id:1/13# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.116+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.AcceptorState$2]: AcceptorState:
>   acceptor-[prepare]->acceptor from:cluster://192.168.0.2:5001
>   instance:4 conversation-id:1/13# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.130+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.AcceptorState$2]: AcceptorState:
>   acceptor-[accept]->acceptor from:cluster://192.168.0.2:5001 instance:4
>   conversation-id:1/13# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.144+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]: Learned and closed instance 4 from
>   conversation 1/13# and the content was Change cluster config,
>   elected:3 as coordinator 2014-01-23 02:08:45.145+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]: LearnerState: learner-[learn]->learner
>   from:cluster://192.168.0.2:5001 instance:4 conversation-id:1/13#
>   2014-01-23 02:08:45.146+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.AtomicBroadcastState$3]: AtomicBroadcastState:
>   broadcasting-[broadcastResponse]->broadcasting conversation-id:1/13#
>   2014-01-23 02:08:45.148+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.c.ClusterState$4]:
>   ClusterState: entered-[configurationChanged]->entered
>   conversation-id:1/13# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.154+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.AcceptorState$2]: AcceptorState:
>   acceptor-[prepare]->acceptor from:cluster://192.168.0.3:5001
>   instance:5 conversation-id:3/17# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.163+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.AcceptorState$2]: AcceptorState:
>   acceptor-[accept]->acceptor from:cluster://192.168.0.3:5001 instance:5
>   conversation-id:3/17# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.175+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]: Learned and closed instance 5 from
>   conversation 3/17# and the content was MemberIsAvailable[ Role:
>   master, InstanceId: 3, Role URI: ha://192.168.0.3:6001?serverId=3,
>   Cluster URI: cluster://192.168.0.3:5001] 2014-01-23 02:08:45.176+0000
>   DEBUG [o.n.c.p.a.m.LearnerState$2]: LearnerState:
>   learner-[learn]->learner from:cluster://192.168.0.3:5001 instance:5
>   conversation-id:3/17# 2014-01-23 02:08:45.178+0000 DEBUG
>   [o.n.c.p.a.m.AtomicBroadcastState$3]: AtomicBroadcastState:
>   broadcasting-[broadcastResponse]->broadcasting conversation-id:3/17#

**neo4j-enterprise messages.log**

> Error while trying to switch to slave
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MismatchingStoreIdException: Expected:StoreId[time:1390358266388, id:-379881635520884869, store version: 13843131341501958], encountered:StoreId[time:1390358433121, id:-6272142992212225740, store version: 13843131341501958]
>       at org.neo4j.com.Client.assertCorrectStoreId(Client.java:302) ~[neo4j-com-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
>       at org.neo4j.com.Client.sendRequest(Client.java:241) ~[neo4j-com-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.MasterClient20.getMasterIdForCommittedTx(MasterClient20.java:359) ~[neo4j-ha-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.checkDataConsistencyWithMaster(HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.java:679) ~[neo4j-ha-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.checkDataConsistency(HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.java:498) ~[neo4j-ha-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.access$900(HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.java:110) ~[neo4j-ha-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher$2.run(HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.java:393) ~[neo4j-ha-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
>   2014-01-23 02:37:10.968+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.h.c.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher]: Attempting to switch to slave in 300s

We also have this in neo4j-enterprise console.log

> 2014-01-23 02:22:10.759+0000 INFO  [Cluster] ServerId 1, moving to slave for master ha://192.168.0.3:6001?serverId=3
>   2014-01-23 02:22:10.777+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Checking store consistency with master
>   2014-01-23 02:22:10.830+0000 INFO  [Cluster] The store does not represent the same database as master. Will remove and fetch a new one from master
>   2014-01-23 02:27:10.839+0000 INFO  [Cluster] ServerId 1, moving to slave for master ha://192.168.0.3:6001?serverId=3
>   2014-01-23 02:27:10.850+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Checking store consistency with master
>   2014-01-23 02:27:10.873+0000 INFO  [Cluster] The store does not represent the same database as master. Will remove and fetch a new one from master
>   2014-01-23 02:32:10.888+0000 INFO  [Cluster] ServerId 1, moving to slave for master ha://192.168.0.3:6001?serverId=3
>   2014-01-23 02:32:10.896+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Checking store consistency with master
>   2014-01-23 02:32:10.916+0000 INFO  [Cluster] The store does not represent the same database as master. Will remove and fetch a new one from master
>   2014-01-23 02:37:10.926+0000 INFO  [Cluster] ServerId 1, moving to slave for master ha://192.168.0.3:6001?serverId=3
>   2014-01-23 02:37:10.935+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Checking store consistency with master
>   2014-01-23 02:37:10.958+0000 INFO  [Cluster] The store does not represent the same database as master. Will remove and fetch a new one from master

Repeated attempts to fetch a new database from the master

Has anyone have any insight as to why the server is "hung" for a lack of better terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the instance failing to start is what you refer to as `neo4j-service`. Further I'm assuming that the embedded instance holds the actual data of your graph db.

In this case stop neo4j on `neo4j-service` (aka the server instance), delete `$NEO4J_HOME/data/graph.db` and start it again. It should then sync the contents of the graph.db from the embedded instance (which I assume to be master).

Comment: I ended up doing this after posting my issue.  This did resolve it.